#  How to sign a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

I am creating a signed applet. The applet works fine without JavaScript, but when 
called from JavaScript it is not working.

I came to know that if we have to call a signed applet using JavaScript, the script should be signed. How do I sign a script 
without using Netscape signtool as signtool is not available now (I think).

My goal is to sign a script.

Comment: By applet, you mean a Java applet?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you still use SignTool to sign scripts. That should still be a part of the Mozilla project. The following article should be helpful:

[Signing Scripts](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-scripts.html)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

http://jmol.sourceforge.net/jslibrary/

```
Jmol.js is a JavaScript library that can be used to simplify development of web pages that include the JmolApplet.
```